# Trying to populate an html option list with jQuery's get method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, servlets

I currently have a servlet setup to send over a list of our active servers. The method grabs the servlet data, processes it, then injects the html into the datalist tag. HTML injection process works, but when I'm splitting the array by the concat separator (which I've done before), I get no values. Below I'll explain with code examples:

HTML:

```
<label for="server_id_text">Server ID: </label>
            <input id="server_id_text" list="server_names" name="server_id" required>
            <datalist id="server_names">
                <!--This gets injected with the active servers grabbed through a get request-->
            </datalist>
```

Javascript connecting to server to get data:

Note: `serverList` is a global variable.

```
var serverList = "";
function setupAutoComplete() {

$.get(baseURL + "/SupportPortal", function (data, status) {
    console.debug("Status with auto comp id: " + status);
    serverList = data;
    console.debug("server list auto comp at post mailing: " + serverList);
});
}
```

This method is called in the function that is called when the `onload` event is called in the `body` tag

Here are the two methods that inject the html:

```
function setupServerName() {
document.getElementById("server_names").innerHTML = getServerListHTML();
}

function getServerListHTML(){
console.debug("Autocomplete process running...");
var servArr = String(serverList).split('*');
var html = '';
var temp = '<option value="{serverName}">';
console.debug("Array:" + servArr.toString());
if (serverList == 'undefined' || servArr.length == 0){
    console.debug("serverList is empty...");
    return '';
}

for (var i =0; i < servArr.length; ++i){
    html += temp.replace("{serverName}", servArr[i]);
}

console.debug("html: " + html);
console.debug("ServList size " + servArr.length);

return html;
}
```

When the page loads, `setupAutoCompelte()` is called first. Then, `setupServerName()` is called.

My issue is that after I load the page, I get the correct response from the server. For instance, I'll get `server1*server2` as a response to the jQuery `$.get(...)` call. Then I go to split the string into an array, and I get back an empty html tag (`<option value="">`);

Also, the debug console info are as follows:

```
Autocomplete process running...
Array:
html: <option value="">
ServList size 1
Status with auto comp id: success
server list auto comp at post mailing: server1*server2
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that your `setupServerName()` function is being called before the AJAX request in `setupAutoComplete()` returns, so your `serverList` is an empty string at that point.  What you need to do is populate your `<datalist>` from inside your AJAX callback in `setupAutoComplete()`.

```
// setup autocomplete datalist

function setupAutoComplete() {

    var $datalist = $('#server_names');

    $.get(baseURL + '/SupportPortal').then(function (data) {

        // update datalist

        if (!data || !data.length) {

            // no servers, empty list

            $datalist.html('');

        } else {

            // create options html:

            // reduce array of server names
            // to HTML string, and set as 
            // innerHTML of the dataset

            $datalist.html(data.split('*').reduce(function (html, server) {
                return html + '<option value="' + server + '">\n';
            },''));
        }
    });
}

// on page load, setup autocomplete

$(function () {
    setupAutoComplete();
});
```

Comment: Wow. I began to use jQuery lightly a few months ago, but I didn't realize how compact it _really_ makes functions. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from "debug console info":

the get function is asyncrhonous so you need to change your setupAutoComplete get part to:

```
$.get(baseURL + "/SupportPortal", function (data, status) {
        console.debug("Status with auto comp id: " + status);
        serverList = data;
        setupServerName();
        console.debug("server list auto comp at post mailing: " + serverList);
    });
```

On page load try to call directly the setupServerName function within the success event of get function. A different approach is to divide the setupServerName function so that the part related to the serverList  variable becomes part of another function.

The serverList  variable is global but its content is filled after the  setupServerName is executed.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I added your change, and it worked!